# Search through rows for user ID's if the have all the values specified in a column list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a table of qualification records that I need to be able to search through, showing only the user_ids that contain all of the course codes AB, CB and DE. I've tried group by, count(*) and having but no matter how I arrange things I still do not get the desired result.

```
record_id      user_id     course_code    
------------------------------------------------
1              1000        AB
2              1000        CB
3              1000        DE
4              1001        AB
5              1002        AB
6              1003        AB
7              1004        AB
8              1005        AB
9              1005        CB
10             1005        DE
```

Running the query I'm trying to achieve should return only user_id's 1000 and 1005.

To add extra complexity, this list of qualifications to search will be dynamically generated by a PHP script based on some user input. So on some occasions may include 10 course_code values and in others only 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from mytable 
where course_code in ('AB', 'CB', 'DE')
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3
```

This assumes that `(user_id, course_code)` tuples are unique across the tables, otherwise you would need to change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct course_code) = 3
```

You can easily change the `where` and `having` clauses to handle more `course_code`s.